# API to manage YARN Capacity Queue

Tags: hadoop, curl, hadoop-yarn

I want to manage YARN capacity Queue using API.
I create the security policy of the Hadoop, I did by curl:

```
hadoop_policy()
{
        curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "${ranger_admin}:${ranger_password}" \
        -d "{ \
            \"allowExceptions\": [], \
            \"denyExceptions\": [], \
            \"dataMaskPolicyItems\": [], \
            \"rowFilterPolicyItems\": [], \
            \"denyPolicyItems\": [], \
            \"description\": \"Securite HDFS pour l'utilisateur ${user}\", \
            \"isAuditEnabled\": true, \
            \"isEnabled\": true, \
            \"name\": \"user_${user}\", \
            \"policyItems\": [ \
                { \
                    \"accesses\": [ \
                        { \
                            \"isAllowed\": true, \
                            \"type\": \"read\" \
                        }, \
                        { \
                            \"isAllowed\": true, \
                            \"type\": \"write\" \
                        }, \
                        { \
                            \"isAllowed\": true, \
                            \"type\": \"execute\" \
                        } \
                    ], \
                    \"conditions\": [], \
                    \"delegateAdmin\": false, \
                    \"groups\": [], \
                    \"users\": [\"${user}\"] \
                } \
            ], \
            \"resources\": { \
                \"path\": { \
                    \"isExcludes\": false, \
                    \"isRecursive\": true, \
                    \"values\": [ \
                        \"/user/${user}\",\"/apps/hive/warehouse/${user}_*\" \
                    ] \
                } \
            }, \
            \"service\": \"${ranger_cluster}_hadoop\", \
            \"version\": 1 \
        }" \
        ${ranger_host}/service/public/v2/api/policy/
        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
                sortieErreur "Erreur de creation de la politique ${policyService} pour l'utilisateur ${user}" 1
        fi
}
```

I have 5 queue, I want manage them via an API,

Comment: You're assuming YARN has an API available like Ranger? The queues are managed by XML files

Comment: Yes I manage YARN by Ranger, but I wrote a scripts to manage the policy Hadoop, Hive and Hbase. Now I want do the same for Yarn

Comment: Defining YARN queues and giving policies to them are two different things

Comment: Not yet I did the manage of the queue. Have you an idea please ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Hadoop 3 and Capacity Scheduler then there is a new alpha-stage API to alter the scheduler configurations.  The endpoint is:

> RM-URL:PORT/ws/v1/cluster/scheduler-conf

It supports queue adding, updating, and removal, and general config updates too.

[Scheduler Configuration Mutation API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Scheduler_Configuration_Mutation_API)

Comment: hello, i also want to pull yarn/RM data for analysis. will this api work. I am trying to query my machine but getting an error  =>  Connection refused * Closing connection 0 curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.56.101:6188; Connection refused.